# php files sharing with user permissions that keeps ftp upload structure of folders and files

Tags: php, sharepoint, file-upload, filesystems, fileshare

We are looking a solution where we can upload files to a linux server via sftp and for the file sharing platform to then see all files and folders we upload

then we need to be able to

- set ownership of files and folders so only certain users can download files
- keep structure of all folders and files
- share files folders with more than 1 user

we would appreciate any recommendations of solutions that are as affordable as possible if not free :)

Comment: I don't really understand the requirements. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: i need a files sharing system that acts like plesk

Comment: in terms of all files and folders appearing as uploaded

Comment: then i need the ability to be able to restrict access e.g. user a can only view user a files whereas admin can view all

Comment: did you get my last comments?

Comment: i have tried 1 solution however it forces you to create virtual directories for the database - it does not automatically take the folders and files from the stuff uploaded via ftp

Comment: what has this to do with sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of these types of apps floating around.  Try google.

http://pfn.sourceforge.net/

http://www.opendocman.com/

Comment: i have installed opendoc man and it is a standard php files sharing package, it does not seem to feature what we need: upload files via ftp (we have 11000 files and folders) we need the files once uploaded to be recognised via the system so we can set access permissions.

Comment: it will manage the files for you once they are on there, getting them to the server, php wont help you with.  php doesnt have a desktop app which you can SFTP files with.

Comment: do you know of a solution where i can sftp files to my server , then they will automatically appear in the files share soft so i can set access of files and folders to certain users?

Comment: You'll just have to google around and look. I'm certain some package out there will work with existing directories.  If you had to, you could use opendocman, and write a quick script to import your existing files into their database structure.